# Executing php code switches the tab to first tab - how to avoid this?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm wondering what's the best solution to my little problem here.

I've a page with few tabs, first one displays the data via mysql_fetch_array. Second tab contains some other data from different class object, which is also displayed via mysql_fetch_array.

On the second tab I've put the sort links and search field which allows to search and sort the data, which reloads the page and displays the first tab again.

I get all the data right, search works, links work, however I want to avoid switching back to the first tab once the code has been executed within the second one.

Is AJAX the only solution here ?

EDIT:

Isn't this a prepared statement ?

```
    public static function SelectObj($obj,$base,$cond) {
    self::$query = "select $obj from ".self::$baseprefix."$base where $cond";
    $out = self::Execute();
    //$array = mysql_fetch_array($out);
    //return $array[$obj];
    return $out;
}

    private static function Execute() {
    $out = mysql_query(self::$query);
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: In general that shouldn't be the only option, you could change the server side building of the page in such a way that the second tab is displayed by default if certain criteria are met.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks for your comments. I'm using prepared statements in my code. Thanks for poiting out the mysqli and PDO, I will definitely take a look into this and switch.

Comment: @Abbys You can't use prepared statements with `mysql_`?

Answer (score 0):

in the back end when the processing is done.save tabid in session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['tabID']=2; //which ever tab u want to be active
```

and in your tabs page.get the tab value and empty the variable

```
    $tabID=1; //default tab u want to show normally
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['tabID'])){
     $tabID=$_SESSION['tabID'];
     unset($_SESSION['tabID']); //unset it so that when u come next time to same page.it ll show only the dafault page
}
```

and in jquery tabs use this

```
$('#tabs').tabs({active:<?php echo $tabID; ?>});
```